# Create list of integers that correspond to a matched date between 2 different lengthed date objects

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, plyr

I have 2 date objects: a list of 73 dates which correspond to the start dates of 73 files which each have 5 days worth of data in them like so:

```
> head(fd)
[1] "1993-01-01" "1993-01-06" "1993-01-11" "1993-01-16" "1993-01-21" "1993-01-26"
```

I then have a large list of 110k+ dates which correspond to observations which are at irregular, non-linear intervals but are classed as a date object like so:

```
> head(dd)
[1] "1993-01-04" "1993-01-10" "1993-01-05" "1993-01-15" "1993-01-18" "1993-01-03"
```

I am trying to create a new list of values which link each of the values in `dd` to a value of `fd` such that if a date in dd is between `1993-01-01` and `1993-01-05` it gets a value of 1 and so on. It is far to inefficient both to code and compute, to use a loop. I tried to do this using the `which` function:

```
i <- which(dd >= fd[-length(fd)] & dd < fd[-1])
```

but this returns a warning:

```
Warning messages:
1: In `>=.default`(dd, fd[-length(fd)]) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
2: In `<.default`(dd, fd[-1]) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

and does not return the required output. It merely returns a list of integers which correspond to values in dd which it believes to be matched that don't apear to follow a logical order. Any suggestions?

For the above summarised data sets I would require a result of

```
>i
[1] 1 2 1 3 4 1
```

as each date in `dd` would correspond to the 1st, 2nd, 1st, 3rd, 4th and 1st date in `fd` respectively.

The match function, as far as I'm aware cannot accomplish this as if you simply use:

```
i <- match(dd, fd)
```

You are returned with a list of mostly NAs where the dates do not exactly match and roughly 365/5 numbers that do correspond to one of the dates in `fd`

Comment: Maybe findInterval() is the function you need.

Answer (score 0):

I think which.min is what you are after.  Try:

```
i <- sapply(dd, function(x)which.min(x > fd) - 1)
```

If a date in dd is less than the smallest date in df, it will return 0. This does assume that df is sorted in ascending order.  I tried it with the following values:

```
fd <- seq.Date(as.Date("1993-01-01"), by="5 days", length=74)
dd <- sample(seq.Date(from = min(fd), to = max(fd) - 1, by="1 day"), 
             size = 1E5, replace = TRUE)
```

On my rather modest laptop, that took 64 seconds.
BTW, "which" (and which.min) is base R.

Edit- the inequality should of course be > not >=.
Also, in this case where fd is a simple sequence, there is obviously a much simpler solution:

```
startDate <- min(fd)
i2 <- as.integer((testSeq-startDate)/5) + 1
```

Dealing with dates earlier than startDate would require some minor refinements.